# ロゼッタONでコンパイルしたものが、arm64でも動くのはなぜですか？

Tags: c, macos

やったこと（ロゼッタONで、コンパイル。arm64で実行）：

```
$ uname -m       
x86_64
$ gcc hoge.c
$ ./a.out 
こんにちは!
$ file ./a.out 
./a.out: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ arch -arm64 zsh
Restored session: Wed Oct 11 09:00:29 JST 2023
$ uname -m    
arm64
$ ./a.out 
こんにちは!
```

x86_64用にコンパイルしたものが arm64で動いています。
なぜなのでしょうか？　どういうときに動かなくなるのでしょうか？

hoge.cの中身は下記です。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  printf("こんにちは!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

---

くどくなるので、詳細は載せませんが、逆の場合も同様で、arm64でコンパイルしたものが、x86_64で動いていました。

Comment: [Rosetta 2](https://support.apple.com/ja-jp/guide/security/secebb113be1/web)は「ARMプロセッサ上でIntel x86_64用アプリケーションを動作させる」技術です。動作環境CPU(Apple Mx)はARMプロセッサですから、結果的にarm64/x86_64両バイナリを実行可能です。